# Dcount function with wildcard characters

Tags: ms-access

I have a table containing project and region column.

```
Project  region
Exp       UK
Exp1      uk/usa
```

Dcount("[project]","[tablename]","[region]='uk'")

It will return 1 instead of 2.

Can someone help how can I count this with wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

Use LIKE with wildcard characters.

Consider:

`Dcount("[project]", "[tablename]", "[region] LIKE 'uk*'")`